# Explain Vs Desc anomalies in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan, describe

What are the differences between EXPLAIN and DESC commands in MySQL ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- [Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) will give you more
  information about a query,
- [describe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html) will give you more
  information about tables or columns.

You can also use EXPLAIN on a table name, in which case it will behave exactly like DESCRIBE.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM `customer`

id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra 
1 SIMPLE customer ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 2
```

vs.

```
DESCRIBE `customer`
Field  Type  Null  Key  Default  Extra 
CustomerID varchar(2) NO      
Cx varchar(3) NO
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html says "The DESCRIBE and EXPLAIN statements are synonyms." And "the MySQL parser treats them as completely synonymous."