# MySQL syntax explanation

Tags: mysql

Really simple question what is the difference between `DESCRIBE` and `EXPLAIN` when using it in a MySQL query ?

They both look as though they product the same results.

Comment: DESCRIBE (and possibly EXPLAIN) are not standard SQL statements. Please specify which DBMS you are asking about.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100247/explain-vs-desc-anomalies-in-mysql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DESCRIBE and EXPLAIN are synonyms when enquiring for the definition of tables, procedures, etc. EXPLAIN (some query) outlines the plan the query optimiser has come up with the perform your command.

12.3.1 and 12.3.2 of the reference manual have the full details.